# Selenium scrape works for individual pages but not in a for loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I wrote code to scrape a series of webpages. When I tested each page individually, the code worked, but when I tried to combine the pages into a for loop, it failed, as I got the error "elementclickinterceptedexception."

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

districts_df = pd.DataFrame()

district_list = [
    {'url':'https://go.boarddocs.com/mabe/mcpsmd/Board.nsf/Public', 'name':'Montgomery County Board of Education'},
    {'url':'https://go.boarddocs.com/nc/cabcs/Board.nsf/public', 'name':'Cabarrus County Schools'},
]

DRIVER_PATH = '/path/to/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

for district in district_list:
    print(district['name'], district['url'])

    url = district['url']
    district_name = district['name']

    driver.get(url)

    meetings = driver.find_element("id", "mainMeetings")
    meetings.click()

    featured = driver.find_element("css selector", ".featured")
    featured.click()

    meeting_content = driver.find_element("id", "btn-print-agenda1")
    meeting_content.click()

    detailed_agenda = driver.find_element("xpath", "//a[@href='#tab-2']")
    detailed_agenda.click()

    agenda_text = driver.find_element("id", "for-print").get_attribute("outerHTML")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(agenda_text, 'html.parser')
    meeting_agenda = soup.text

    districts_df = districts_df.append({'url': url,
                                        'district_name': district_name,
                                        'agenda': meeting_agenda}, ignore_index=True)
```

I tried to fix this issue by having the scraper wait longer before clicking. Here was what I tried for the first click:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

    try:
        meetings = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "mainMeetings")))
        meetings.click()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        print("Trying to click on the button again")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", meetings)
```

Then the driver was able to click on the "Meetings" button, but failed to click the "featured" button. It feels like if I went through and replaced every click() command with the try/except code, it would make my code exceptionally complex, cumbersome and difficult to read and debug. Is there a more elegant solution? Something that I'm missing? I also still don't understand why the code works for any one individual page, but not when I put it in a for loop.

Comment: You need to click a clickable element, the element that you're trying to click `(By.ID, "mainMeetings")` is a span element.

Comment: Replacing EC.presence_of_element_located with EC.element_to_be_clickable in some cases, or switching from clicking on a <span> element to an <a> element, helped, and now the code works!